# cannot convert 'double' to 'const char*'

Tags: c

Right now I have this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fib(){
        double pi = 0;
        double n = 4;
        double d = 1;
        double a;
        clock_t begin = clock();
        for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++){
         a=2*(i%2)-1;
         pi+=a*n/d;
         d+=2;
        }
        clock_t end = clock();
        double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf(pi);
        printf(time_spent);

};
int main() {
    fib();
    return 0;
}
```

and I get cannot convert 'double' to 'const char*'` on printf(pi); and printf(time_spent); How can I get pi and time_spent to print correctly?

Comment: Pass a format string to `printf`.

Comment: `printf()` is for formatted output. Takes a `const char *` as an argument. In your case it should be `printf("%f",pi)` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit those lines:

`printf("%lf",pi)`
`printf("%lf",time_spent)`

`printf()` is for formatted output that takes a `const char *` as an argument.
There are many format specifiers defined in C. Take a look at the following list:

`%i` or `%d` for    `int`
`%c` for    `char`
`%f` for    `float`
`%s` for    `string`
`%lf` for    `long float (double)`